# Is there a no point symbology option in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology

I'm sure it exists, but is there a way to set a point layer to have no symbology. This works best for cities as you just want to display the name, and not necessarily show the location. The way I do it now, is by picking a symbol and making the fill and outline to have "no color"

Comment: Setting to "no color" works. Area there any issues with this technique?

Comment: That's how I do it.

Comment: What's wrong with your current method? I guess it feels a little hacky but if we complained about all the hacky things ArcGIS makes us do we'd never get anything done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the Layer Properties dialog Symbology tab and click on the Symbol.  On the Symbol Selector dialog click Properties.

[image]

Then uncheck the symbol on the layers list at the left.

[image]

Click ok until you close all the dialogs.

Comment: So it's similar to my method, just with a different symbol, does the size need to be adjusted to zero?

Comment: No you just uncheck it, then no symbol will be displayed for the layer.

Comment: Then you just save this to your styles and you always have it available to you.

Comment: or set size to 0.00 in the first image. colour can also be set none.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to assign layer display transparency to 100 percent.